# A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "VISIBLE" at position 749)

Tags: php, mysql

**Thanks In Advance .. 
Here's Mysql Code, Any Help Finding The Solution is greatly appreciated**

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Wed Sep 12 11:13:20 2018
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering
SET
    @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS = @@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET
    @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET
    @OLD_SQL_MODE = @@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema sdb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema sdb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `sdb` DEFAULT CHARACTER 
SET
    utf8 ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema simpleraccountsdb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
USE `sdb` ;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Conacts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Conacts` ( `ContactID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ConactAddressID` INT NOT NULL, `ContactCategoryID` INT NOT NULL, `ConactItemID` INT NOT NULL, `ConactDTTID` INT NOT NULL, `ContactNickName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `ContactDescription` TEXT NULL, `ConactFirstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ContactMidName` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ContactLastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ConactNumber1` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ConactNumber2` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ConactImage` LONGBLOB NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`ContactID`), UNIQUE INDEX `ContactID_UNIQUE` (`ContactID` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Item`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Item` ( `ItemID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ItemCategoryID` INT NOT NULL, `ItemUnitCounterID` INT NOT NULL, `ItemCostID` INT NOT NULL, `ItemDTTID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Stores Product Expiary/Warranty Data Time', `ItemName` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `ItemDescription` TEXT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX `ItemID_UNIQUE` (`ItemID` ASC) VISIBLE, PRIMARY KEY (`ItemID`), CONSTRAINT `FKItemContact` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Conacts` (`ConactItemID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    NO ACTION 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Address` ( `AddressID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `AddressCategoryID` INT NOT NULL, `Address1` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `Address2` VARCHAR(255) NULL, `AddressCountry` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `AddressState` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `AddressDistrict` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `AddressCity` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `AddressPostalcode` VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`AddressID`), UNIQUE INDEX `AddressID_UNIQUE` (`AddressID` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `FKContactAddressID` FOREIGN KEY (`AddressID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Conacts` (`ConactAddressID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    CASCADE 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        CASCADE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Category` ( `CategoryID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Ask for Category Type (Contact,Expense,Purchasable these are the root types) while creating a new category\nwhile removing CAt : when item no longer in any Other category then remove the items along with category', `CategoryParentID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Keeps it\'s Parent Category\'s ID', `CategoryName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `CategoryDescription` VARCHAR(45) NULL, UNIQUE INDEX `ConactsCategoryID_UNIQUE` (`CategoryID` ASC) VISIBLE, PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`), CONSTRAINT `FKCategoryContactID` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Conacts` (`ContactCategoryID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    NO ACTION 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKCategoryParnetID` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryParentID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Category` (`CategoryID`) 
        ON 
        DELETE
            NO ACTION 
            ON 
            UPDATE
                NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKCategoryItemID` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Item` (`ItemCategoryID`) 
                ON 
                DELETE
                    NO ACTION 
                    ON 
                    UPDATE
                        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKCategoryAddressID` FOREIGN KEY (`CategoryID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Address` (`AddressCategoryID`) 
                        ON 
                        DELETE
                            NO ACTION 
                            ON 
                            UPDATE
                                NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Bill`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Bill` ( `BillID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `BillDTTID` INT NOT NULL, `BillPaid` DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL, `BillDews` DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL, `BillTotal` DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`BillID`), UNIQUE INDEX `BillID_UNIQUE` (`BillID` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Invoice`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Invoice` ( `InvoiceID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'InvoiceID,ItemID,CustomerID & InvoiceTimeStampID  searched together should bring out the Prices priced for products at that time for that customer...', `BillID` INT NOT NULL, `InvoiceDTTID` INT NOT NULL, `InvoiceItemID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'InvoiceID,ItemID,CustomerID & InvoiceTimeStampID  searched together should bring out the Prices priced for products at that time for that customer', `InvoiceContactID` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Invoice Estimations is generated by Backend Code From Db table\nInvoiceID,ItemID,CustomerID & InvoiceTimeStampID  searched together should bring out the Prices priced for products at that time for that customer after already created', PRIMARY KEY (`InvoiceID`), UNIQUE INDEX `InvoiceID_UNIQUE` (`InvoiceID` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `FKInvoiceBill` FOREIGN KEY (`BillID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Bill` (`BillID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    NO ACTION 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKInvoiceItem` FOREIGN KEY (`InvoiceItemID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Item` (`ItemID`) 
        ON 
        DELETE
            NO ACTION 
            ON 
            UPDATE
                NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKInvoiceConacts` FOREIGN KEY (`InvoiceContactID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Conacts` (`ContactID`) 
                ON 
                DELETE
                    NO ACTION 
                    ON 
                    UPDATE
                        NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`Cost`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`Cost` ( `CostID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `CostDTTID` INT NOT NULL, `CostBought` DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL, `CostSold` DECIMAL(12, 2) NULL, `CostDiscounted` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `CostTargetSale` VARCHAR(45) NULL, `CostTargetBuy` VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`CostID`), UNIQUE INDEX `CostID_UNIQUE` (`CostID` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `FKItemCostID` FOREIGN KEY (`CostID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Item` (`ItemCostID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    NO ACTION 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`user` ( `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `userDTTID` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `username` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL, `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, `LoggedIn` TINYINT NULL, `Activated` TINYINT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`userID`), UNIQUE INDEX `userID_UNIQUE` (`userID` ASC) VISIBLE);
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`DateTimeTracker`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`DateTimeTracker` ( `DTTID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `DTTCreated` DATETIME NULL, `DTTModified` DATETIME NULL, `DTTUpdated` DATETIME NULL, `DTTDestroyed` DATETIME NULL, `DTTPurchaseTarget` DATETIME NULL, `DTTPurchased` DATETIME NULL, `DTTStock` DATETIME NULL, `DTTSaleTaget` DATETIME NULL, `DTTSold` DATETIME NULL, `DTTRefund` DATETIME NULL, `DTTExpiry` DATETIME NULL, `DTTToBePaid` DATETIME NULL, `DTTPaid` DATETIME NULL, `DTTPeriodStart` DATETIME NULL, `DTTPeriodEnd` DATETIME NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`DTTID`), UNIQUE INDEX `DTTID_UNIQUE` (`DTTID` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDCost` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Cost` (`CostDTTID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    NO ACTION 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDUser` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`user` (`userDTTID`) 
        ON 
        DELETE
            CASCADE 
            ON 
            UPDATE
                CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDBill` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Bill` (`BillDTTID`) 
                ON 
                DELETE
                    NO ACTION 
                    ON 
                    UPDATE
                        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDInvoice` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Invoice` (`InvoiceDTTID`) 
                        ON 
                        DELETE
                            CASCADE 
                            ON 
                            UPDATE
                                CASCADE, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDItem` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Item` (`ItemDTTID`) 
                                ON 
                                DELETE
                                    NO ACTION 
                                    ON 
                                    UPDATE
                                        NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `FKDTTIDConacts` FOREIGN KEY (`DTTID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Conacts` (`ConactDTTID`) 
                                        ON 
                                        DELETE
                                            NO ACTION 
                                            ON 
                                            UPDATE
                                                NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sdb`.`UnitCounter`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sdb`.`UnitCounter` ( `UnitCounterID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `BuyingTargetUnit` INT NULL, `BoughtUnit` INT NULL, `SellingTargetUnit` INT NULL, `SoldUnit` INT NULL, `ReturnUnit` INT NULL, `FaultyUnit` INT NULL, `WastedUnit` INT NULL, `UnsoldUnit` INT NULL, `ExpiredUnit` INT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`UnitCounterID`), UNIQUE INDEX `UnitCounterID_UNIQUE` (`UnitCounterID` ASC) VISIBLE, CONSTRAINT `FKItemUnitCounterID` FOREIGN KEY (`UnitCounterID`) REFERENCES `sdb`.`Item` (`ItemUnitCounterID`) 
ON 
DELETE
    CASCADE 
    ON 
    UPDATE
        CASCADE) ENGINE = InnoDB;
    SET
        SQL_MODE = @OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET
        FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET
        UNIQUE_CHECKS = @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `VISIBLE` is only a keyword in MySQL 8.0. Are you sure that's the version you're running?

Comment: The error is clear, you have to debug your code and find where the comma or bracket are missing

Comment: thank you guyz please be with me i am new to this.. 
--Nick-- .. This is forward engineered code using Mysql workbench 8 .. Ran using 
Xampp :
>>PhpMyadmin Server version: 10.1.35-MariaDB, 
>>Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.9
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 2015040
>>PhpMyAdmin 4.8.3

--sfili_81-- Googling to Learn how to debug this .. thanks 
Looking Forward to your help in fixing the entire code..

Comment: Nick your's was a great hint though.. :) I believe version is the issue.. but looking forward to getting both of your help

Comment: i guess phpMyAdmin still doesn't support mysql 8 .. let's see what i can do ..

Comment: Installed Mysql 8 server seperately .. found out that mysql workbench is seriously buggy .. No longer stuck on the VISIBLE syntax error though .. 
Bug 1: Upon Importing the diagram code, workbench partially generates the db upto the error .. but not shown in schema list.. 
Bug 2: While Importing everytime it's shown the same error,even though the sql file was changed without renaming it..  May be caching issue ..

Comment: Alhamdulillah fixed many errors .. last errors were missing indexes .. and final issue were default/expression mismatch issue .. Thanks guyz.. Mainly Nick
Unfortunately I do not see any option to upvote you .. Haven't used stackoverflow account before..

Answer (score 0):

Please compare your installed mysql version and target mysql version of the Workbench. If both are different then you can manually change the target mysql version of workbench.

Please refer the link to [Modeling Preferences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-modeling.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the default it is `VISIBLE`, just remove the word "VISIBLE" from the SQL script.